# Is it incorrect to use Fischer Projections for carbons that don't have stereocenters?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, structural-formula

For example:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/L-%C3%84pfels%C3%A4ure_Fischer.svg/110px-L-%C3%84pfels%C3%A4ure_Fischer.svg.png]

Is a cross specifically used for stereocenter representation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to IUPAC it is not incorrect for using it to depict carbohydrates being stereogenic or not. However here is an excerpt from the link listed below:

> The use of
>   Fischer projections in non-carbohydrates is problematic. Any drawings
>   of this type are necessarily ambiguous since it is unclear whether the
>   author of the drawing intended to make a Fischer projection or simply
>   happened to draw a diagram in that orientation. Molecules depicted in
>   the style of Fischer projections are likely to be recognized as such
>   when they contain at least two acyclic stereo- genic centers oriented
>   vertically, although such interpretation is not guaranteed. Molecules
>   containing a single stereogenic center pose even greater problems
>   since it is often convenient to separate the four ligands by equal
>   angles whether or not a single stereoisomer is intended. Accordingly,
>   although Fischer projections of carbohydrates are acceptable, similar
>   depictions of non-carbohydrates should be used only when the viewer of
>   the diagram is certain to understand that the diagram was intended to
>   represent a Fischer projection. Fischer projections should be avoided
>   where ambiguity is possible, including when used in computer
>   applications.

[image]

See more here (page 37-38):

http://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/2006/pdf/7810x1897.pdf